# E2170 Cannot override a non-virtual method on Updating DSharp

Tags: delphi-xe2, dsharp+

I am trying to update DSharp to the latest release. Before doing that I updated Spring4D successfully.

When I tried to update DSharp and build DSharp.Core.DelphiXE2.bpl I had the error message

> "[DCC Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(54): E2170 Cannot
> override a non-virtual method"

Here below is the excerpt of the unit with line 54

```
TCustomIterator<T> = class(TIterator<T>)
  private
    fProc: TIteratorProc<T>;
  public
    constructor Create(const proc: TIteratorProc<T>);

    function Clone: TIterator<T>; override;
    function MoveNext: Boolean; override; // line 54
  end;
```

Any idea of what I am missing out on?

My machine runs a Win 7, 32-bit

Many thanks
Alberto

Comment: Sounds like something you should be asking the DSharp author about